# Naming conventions for MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I would like to get some opinions since I am thinking about creating structure for my new application and I am struggling with names for tables so I thought maybe you can give me some ideas. App has users and users can create projects while projects can have multiple keywords. So users are in one-to-many relationship with projects and projects are in many-to-many relationships with tags.

So having table `users` I suppose projects table should be `users_projects`. But what about keywords? Should it be `users_projects_keywords` ? And what about pivot table since I think it is kinda bad to name it like `users_projects_to_users_projects_keywords` or something like that. I would be grateful for a tips.

Edit:
I always thought that one-to-many relationships should be called like x_y where y belongs to x. Is it not a good practice ?

Comment: I like: projects, users, projects_users. Core tables have single letter aliases (p,u) and linking tables have two letter aliases (pu). The user_id column in the linking table links to the user_id column in user table.

Comment: @Strawberry But is this projects table really a core one ? Since it depends on users in one-to-many ? I am concerned about situation where there can be two kinds of projects with various columns so they can't be placed in one table. Like dev projects and user projects.

Comment: I'm just talking about my basic naming conventions. If the design is more complicated then the naming pattern may need to be more sophisticated to reflect that. But don't agonise over this stuff. It gets easier with practice.

Answer (score 0):

I would have `users`, `projects`, `keywords`, `project_keywords`. I would use foreign keys to define the relationships between the tables. For example, `projects` would have a column such as `createdby_userid`, referring to the `users.user_id` column.

Comment: Hmm I always thought that one-to-many relationships should be named like users_projects with user_id in this table. What in a situation when there would be also admin projects ? I can't then name my table projects since there are user_projects called like that. Hmmm it's tough :)

Answer (score 0):

One idea:

There could be three dictionaries:

- Table `users` should have `id` and other data.
- Table `projects` as well.
- And so table `keywords`.

Then you create "linking" (relations) tables:

- `users_projects` with column `id, id_user, id_project`
- `projects_keywords` with `id, id_project, id_keyword`

**EDIT**:
Maybe it indeed would be rational to include `id_user` into table `projects` as mentioned by @Laurence.